# Algorithm for distance based-activation of multiple actors

Tags: optimization, open-world

In our game we have many kind of actors that to activate certain behaviors can have one or more than one distance-based conditions. For instance a Rat Enemy could have

```
if(DistanceToPlayer < 50 && !_charging)
  charge_player();
else if(DistanceToPlayer > 100 && !_roaming)
  start_inoffensive_roaming();
else if(DistanceToFood < 10 && _hunger > 0.90f)
  eat_food();
else if(DistanceToFood < 30 && _hunger > 0.90f && !_moving_to_food)
  move_toward_food();
//and so on...
```

The same actor can be scripted to have interactions with many other elements of the game world, and being an "open world"-ish game I need to keep performance impact to a minimum.

My current approach is to refresh the distance checks if either of the 2 subjects has moved, even by a small amount: the rat "subscribes" itself to the position changes of the player (and of the rat itself), and to the position changes of all food items loaded in the world. If either of the three position changes, the rat will call its `UpdateConditions()` method on the next frame.

I might be over-optimizing it, but unless the rat is static, I'm doing 120 positional calculation per second due to the rat simply roaming around (60 `DistanceToPlayer`+ 60 `DistanceToFood`). I'd love to reduce the refresh rate when the calculated positions are far from trigger points, and maintain precision when the positions are close to trigger points. Is there a common approach for this kind of problem?

Comment: Do you do any broad-phase binning, like a quadtree or spatial hash, to be able to query or apply subscriptions only to "nearby" items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to not check every frame for an update. Both people and creatures have a reaction time to a change in stimuli, so it is totally reasonable to check for updates less frequently. Consider how far any given unit is traveling in 1 second. Are they ever traveling fast enough where they will miss a potential target? It will depend on your game but probably not. In your update function, simply increment a timer and check if the timer is above the set point. If it is, subtract the set point and perform the distance checks.

Faster units may need faster reaction times, but even if you set it to 0.25 seconds, you only have 4 checks per second instead of 60 while having little to no observable impact on gameplay.

From a more advanced perspective, games with larger numbers of units may use update scheduling. A central unit manager queues up a certain number of units to update each frame. This spreads the processing of all the units out over multiple frame updates and helps keep the processing load consistent instead of getting hit with big waves of processing when a bunch of unit update timers finish. If you have units of varying complexity, a processing time score can be assigned and used to decide how many units to update in the frame. Add units to the processing list for the current frame and add their scores together until a max processing score is reached, then process the selected units.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!